# MySQL date wildcard performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, date, wildcard

I have an index on a table that has several columns, some of which are dates. I want to reuse this index on another query, but pass a wildcard for the date.

A simplified MADE-UP example query:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM purchaseOrders 
 WHERE purchaseOrderDate > 0 AND totalPrice > 10
 //and other columns
```

How should I wildcard the date?

NOTE: The index already exists. I would prefer not to create another index if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE (purchaseOrderDate > $some_value OR $some_value is null)
AND totalPrice > 10
```